# Can you not delete the primary workgroup in aws athena after its been created? I would like to make sure im not getting charged for the resource

Tags: terraform, amazon-athena, terraform-provider-aws, workgroup

I've deployed the database with terraform,

I destroyed the database,

I went to UI to delete the workgroup and got an error. ERRROR: (Error deleting workgroup
primary workGroup could not be deleted)

I would like to ensure that i am not getting charged for the resource.

If you have any knowledge on how to delete an empty workgroup using athena

Comment: Are there any resources dependent on the workgroup?

Comment: No, nothing is tied to workgroup. and its been emptied.

Answer (score 1):

> The primary workgroup cannot be deleted.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/workgroups-create-update-delete.html#deleting-workgroups